# preg_replace to allow everything?

Tags: php

I am trying to find a way so preg_replace allows everything in the URL....

at the moment my code allows `space`, `/` and `alphabetical` characters....

First of all I need to know if there is a way to allow everything and i mean every single character in preg_replace?

and if not then I need to allow `+` and `-` and `_` and `'` and `++` and basically all the special characters?

here is my current code:

```
$category = preg_replace('/[^i<>@&\/\sA-Za-z0-9_]/', '', $_GET['category']);
```

could someone please help me out with this?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: sorry I should have explained it better:

I am working on an online shop PHP/mysql...

I am trying to display the products under each category in the category list page.

for example:

when someone clicks on the category 1 the products under category 1 will p1, p2, p3 etc and they will be pulled from the mysql database like so:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
// Run a select query to get my letest 6 items
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "config/connect.php";


$category = preg_replace('/[^i<>@&\/\sA-Za-z0-9_]/', '', $_GET['category']);



$cList2 = "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='".$category."'  LIMIT 35" ;
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $price = $row["price"];
             $category = $row["category"];
             $details = $row["details"];
             $stock = $row["stock"];
             $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
             $cList2 .= '<table  style="border:solid 1px #EBEBEB; margin-top:10px;" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="21%"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img style="border:solid 1px #E2E2E2; margin:10px;" src="inventory_images/' . $id . 'Image1.jpg" width="124" height="124" /></a></td>
    <td width="4%"><div style="border-right:solid 1px #E2E2E2; width:2px; height:120px; margin-left:5px;"></div></td>
    <td valign="top" width="48%"><table style="margin-left:10px;" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $product_name . '</a></td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td><div style="font-weight:normal; text-align:left; height:90px; overflow:hidden; margin-top:10px;">' . $details . '</div></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td valign="top" width="24%"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="40"><strong style="color:#999;">Price:</strong> £' . $price . '<br/>' . $stock . '</td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><form method="post" action="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><input type="submit" class="button" name="button" id="button" value="Add to cart" /></form></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>';
    }
}
} else {
    $cList2 = "We have no products listed in our store yet";
}

?>
```

so, some of the categories name have some special characters like `+` sign or `-` sign or `++` sign etc... currently those categories with `+` sign `++` sign or `-` sign would not display their products in the category list page BUT when i remove the `+` sign or `-` sign etc they will display their products correctly!

That is what I am trying to work out.

**EDIT: here is how I add/insert my products into db: please ignore mysql query as I will be changing it to mysqli once I am finished with the rest of the production....**

```
<?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['product_name'])) {

    $product_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_name']);
    $price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
        $quantity = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['quantity']);
    $shipping = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['shipping']);
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
    $details = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['details']);
    $manufactor = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['manufactor']);
    $special = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['special']);
    $stock = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['stock']);
    // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM products WHERE product_name='$product_name' LIMIT 1");
    $productMatch = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productMatch > 0) {
        echo 'Sorry you tried to place a duplicate "Product Name" into the system, <a href="add.php">click here</a>';
        exit();
    }
    // Add this product into the database now
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (product_name, price, quantity, shipping, details, category, manufactor, special, stock, date_added) 
        VALUES('$product_name','$price','$quantity','$shipping','$details','$category','$manufactor','$special','$stock',now())") or die (mysql_error());
     $pid = mysql_insert_id();
    // Place image in the folder 
    $newname = "$pid.jpg";
foreach($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] as $i => $tmpName) {
    if ($tmpName){
        move_uploaded_file( $tmpName, "../inventory_images/{$pid}Image{$i}.jpg");
    }
}
    header("location: add.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: `.` is a special character in RegEx, `/(.*)/` will match everything.  If you really want to remove **everything** from the string like you say, then do: `$category = '';`.

Comment: whats with the downvotes? I would love to know the reason behind the downvotes?

Comment: @SamSullivan, I don't want to remove everything! I want to allow everything!!

Comment: `preg_replace()` will take everything matched from the regular expression and replace it with the string in parameter two..which means you are removing "everything".  What are you trying to accomplish if you want to allow everything?  Why do you need any regular expression then?

Comment: Everything is allowed by default

Comment: @SamSullivan, $category = ''; won't do anything!! did you mean $category = '', $_GET['category']);

Comment: @SamSullivan, I've edited my question. please view the updated question.

Comment: @RoyalBg, if everythings allowed then why `$category =  $_GET['category']);` doesn't work?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to remove those special characters?  Then you want to change your `preg_replace()` to contain unwanted characters, here: `$category = preg_replace("/[_'\+\-]/", '', $_GET['category']);`.  Notice that `+` and `-` are escaped (`\+\-`) since they are reserved regex characters. (you don't need to worry about `++` since both `+` will be removed).

Comment: @SamSullivan, I don't know how else I can explain it. sorry I am a bit confused myself!!! I've tried your code and it didn't work... let me explain it a bit better. lets say I have a category called `MANCHESTER/London's` this category would not display its products because of `'` sign. but it will work fine if i remove the `'` sign.

Comment: Your problems arises from the single quotes which break you query string. You should insert encoded quotes into the DB, search them by encoded string, and output decoded. I guess you can look at htmlspecialchars() function

Comment: My code does exactly that @user3261580: http://ideone.com/68IZ2D -- your problem may be arising from something else, maybe what Royal mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is allowed by default to be contained in a string. You did not tell us from the start that you want to put this string into the database and then extract it to show to the users.

In this case, you need to not break the query string and in the same time, to not show escaped quotes like `\'` We all are users, and we all know nobody wants his name to be `O\'Brian`.

The fastest way I see her is to decode the special chars into entities, and output them back to the user the way he wants them to see.

The logic flow is simple. E.g.: User puts the integer `5` but for some reason `5` is not allowed character. Your cryptology system alerts and you make simple encryption, you add `+1` to it. So you insert into the db the integer `6`. When you later extract this character, you know it's encrypted and you decrypt it with simply subtracting `-1` from it. So you again, output 5.

Very rough example

```
<?php

$category = "MANCHESTER/London's";

$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='".$category."'  LIMIT 35";

var_dump($query);

/*
 * 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='MANCHESTER/London's'  LIMIT 35' (length=69) 
 * The quatation will stop before `s`
 */

$cat_encoded = htmlentities($category, ENT_QUOTES);

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='".$cat_encoded."'  LIMIT 35";
var_dump($query2);

/*
 * 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='MANCHESTER/London&#039;s'  LIMIT 35'
 */

echo $cat_encoded;

/*
 * MANCHESTER/London's
 */
```

In this example you can query your DB without breaking the query string because of raw quotes sent and also you can output to the user the decoded value without any problem - if you try to print the entities they will show as special characters to the end user, but won't insert into DB as ones.

Take a look here http://php.net/htmlentities and here http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: @user3261580 did you try it :)

Comment: try what? your code? as i said it didn't make sense. at least it didn't make sense to me so No.. I didn't try it... :) never mind.... I won't bother you anymore... I'll get on a forum or something...

Comment: @user3261580 just try it. When you INSERT into the db, surround your `category` varialbe with `htmlentities()`. When you select - also do it. And then when you do this `$category = $row["category"];` it all should be ok ;-) You'd better try to understand be, rather than reject it :)

Comment: @user3261580 my code does not replicate your code it just examples how the string is decoded when you interact with database, and how it's encoded when you print it. That's why my code does nothing but print. If you insist I can make a simple INSERT, then simple SELECT and then simple output, to prove my point. But I guess if you just make 2 changes in your code you will understand me faster than if I make a half-app to show this simple thing

Comment: Thats the thing, I don't know what are 2 simple changes that I need to make in my code in order to make it work! I rather understand it and I don't want to ask someone to write me a code but without an example I wouldn't be able to understand it. I tried `$category = htmlentities($_GET['category']);` I don't know how close I am !?

Comment: The problem is that you already has inserted in your database non-escaped string somehow? (how?) What exactly could be a category that contains special chars in your database? Maybe it has slashes or something?

Comment: @user3261580 OK, I saw your edit. You add escaped string which adds slashes before each quote -> `\'`.Кяе the same function while SELECTING. `$category = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['category'])` or mysqli_real_escape_string, but you should not mix them

Comment: sorry I'm not sure what you really mean!

Comment: @user3261580 read this article, everything will get clear for your, if you read it all http://kunststube.net/escapism/

Comment: :) I've already read that a few hours ago believe it or not... Thanks anyway... okay, I'm off to the forum(s)...

Comment: Strange then :) Read it twice. You must understand the logic, not just using examples. GL with the forums :)

Comment: solved the issue with the `'` sign ;).. it wasn't as complicated as some made it to be.... Thanks to the guys who downvoted this question I won't be providing the answer.. so if anyone has the same issue in thefuture they can go through the hell that I went through to sort it out...